# VBA, Error 400, switching between spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

I call from a spreadsheet module a function that does some processing in another sheet and returns an integer. I then want to write that integer in a cell in the sheet from where the function has been called. I receive an error 400, I guess I do not correctly handle the switching between the sheets.

Could you help me with that?

```
Function lastNonZero(Rng As Range) As Integer

 i = 19
 Do While ActiveCell.Value = 0
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Activate
   i = i - 1
 Loop
lastNonZero = i
End Function
```

Extract from the Sub, located in Sheet A's module:

```
For j = startRow To startRow + (nRows - 1)
        Worksheets("B").Select
        Range("Y" & j).Activate
        k = lastNonZero(Worksheets("B").Range("Y" & j))
        Worksheets("A").Range("BZ" & j) = k
Next j
```

Comment: Do you mean that the for loop is in a Sub which is located on Sheet A?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I mean, very appreciate your help

Comment: on what line do you get the error? The range passed as an argument to `lastNonZero` is never used in the function, which is probably not what you mean to do.

Comment: I already get the error in  the line befor I call the function,i.e.,Range("Y" & j).Activate........afterwards the input to the function is in sheet B and the function processing should be done in sheet B and return an integer, this integer should then be written to a cell in Sheet A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the `Range("Y" & j)` line with:

```
Worksheets("B").Range("Y" & j).Activate
```

When you call `Range(xxx)` in a Sheet's module, it refers to a range in that sheet, whether it is selected or not. But if the sheet is not selected and you try to select/activate the range, it will return an error because you can't select a range on a sheet that is not the active sheet.

ps: that does not change the fact that on the next line (`k = lastNonZero(Worksheets("B").Range("Y" & j))`), the argument is not used in the `lastNonZero` function).

Comment: i will try  out in a couple of minutes, and give you then the points if it works, thanks for the help, you are right about the last line, I forgot to remove the argument in the function, it is not necessary anymore